# Difference between git rm cached and git reset HEAD

Tags: git, version-control

I am confused with `git rm --cached` I guess.
I have a repository and a file committed. I modify the file and I do: `git add myfile`
The file is now staged.
When I do `git status`:

```
# On branch master   
# Changes to be committed:  
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)  
#  
#       modified:   com/main/StringMain.java  
#
```

Now the file is a modified tracked file. So I assume that is in the staging area. So I can't understand what is the meaning of the recommendation `(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`. So I did: `git rm --cached` instead followed by a `git commit`. But this seems to removed my file from being tracked and made it untracked.
If I do `git status`:

```
# On branch master  
# Untracked files:  
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  
#  
#       com/  
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So what has happened?

Answer (score 15):

Here is one way to think about it:

```
git rm --cached [file]
```

This simply removes a file from being tracked (the state a file is in after it is added - i.e.  *git add [file]*)

```
git reset HEAD [file]
```

This simply continues to keep tracking changes to the file, but will place it back into the 'unstaged' area.

Here is an example.

First, I created 4 untracked files:

```
$ for i in {A..D}; do touch $i; echo "First line" > $i; done
$ ls
A   B   C   D
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    A
    B
    C
    D

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Next, I track them using git add, then I will commit the changes:

```
$ git add .

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   A
    new file:   B
    new file:   C
    new file:   D

$ git commit -m "First Commit"
[master 6e8d625] First Commit
 4 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 A
 create mode 100644 B
 create mode 100644 C
 create mode 100644 D

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now I will modify file A so git picks up the change, then I will add the changed file to the staging area:

```
$ echo "First line of file A" > A

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   A

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git add A

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   A
```

*Now this is where the differences matter.*

The **first example** that I will give you is what happens when you use **git rm --cached** :

```
$ git rm --cached A
rm 'A'

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    A

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    A
```

Notice how file A is now untracked, much like how it was prior to adding it into git in the very beginning (when "*git add .*" was used).

Now, the **second example** is if I were to use **git reset HEAD** instead:

```
$ git reset HEAD A
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   A

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   A

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Here you will notice that it resets the status of file A back to an unstaged state, but still continues to track the changes of it.

Answer (score 7):

`git rm --cached` removes the file from the index.

`git reset HEAD` resets the index version of the file back to its state in the `HEAD` commit.

So the difference is that the first removes the file, while the second reverts it to the last committed version.

---

To verify this, you can use `git diff` to compare the working tree to the index, and `git diff --cached` to compare the index to the head commit.

When you run `git rm --cached`, the modified file is removed entirely from the index.  It is still present in the working directory and the last commit.  If you compare the index with the last commit:

```
git diff --cached modified_file
```

You'll see that the modified file is not present in the index.  This is confirmed by:

```
git status
```

Which will show the file as being scheduled for deletion on commit.  Your working directory was not affected by `git rm --cached`, because `--cached` works directly in the index.

Comment: So you mean that `git rm --cached` removes the file from the "database" of `git?Is this what you mean by the index? I thought that `cached` refers to the staging area which is something between the commit and the untracked. If what I am saying is correct I can't understand why the `rm cached` then removes from the git db

Comment: Also I do `git add` the change.Then I do `git log --decorate --graph --oneline` and I see `HEAD` on the latest commit.If I do `git reset HEAD com/main/StringMain.java` then the `git log --decorate --graph --oneline` still shows the same thing. So how is `HEAD` affected?

Comment: The index and the staging area are the same thing. The index is a stepping stone for a commit. The act of committing permanently stores the state of the index as a new HEAD commit.

Comment: @Andomar Unfortunately, `git rm --cached` does not always unstage a change. For example, if you modify a tracked file, add the modification to the index, then run `git rm --cached`, it will not remove the modification from the index, but, instead, it will put in the index the file to be deleted at the same time `git status`will tell the file is untracked ?!?! Confusing indeed.

Comment: My main case for using this is that I did `git add .` and then I decided to modify the `.gitignore`. So I want to use one of these two commands (`rm` or `reset` as in your answer) prior to doing `git add .` again. Are the two commands identical in my use-case? Or does `git reset HEAD` actually change the working directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you remove a file from your stage area (git rm file) so it removes the file from your working directoy and your staging area , now lets remove it again but after you staged it , so you have it staged but not on your working directory , if you use git rm --cached file , you get your file back to your working directory (also git doesnt track it anymore , it wont tell you to stage it ), but if you use git reset HEAD file , the file is deleted from the stage area without going back to your working directory .